# Namespaces not found by the compiler

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have several files, listed just below, wherein I define some namespaces and classes. Then in one of the files I am trying to incorporate the classes from the others. The issue is that the compiler seems to not be able to find my namespaces.

charon.cpp

chin.cpp

chout.cpp

main.cpp

My namespaces are **charon**, **charon_in**, and **charon_out**. The main problems come up on a particular file, ***charon.cpp***, so here is that file and ***chin.cpp*** too.

The errors:

```
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/sys/charon.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/sys/charon.o sys/charon.cpp
sys/charon.cpp:6:17: error: ‘charon_in’ is not a namespace-name
sys/charon.cpp:6:26: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
sys/charon.cpp:7:17: error: ‘charon_out’ is not a namespace-name
sys/charon.cpp:7:27: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
sys/charon.cpp:15:5: error: ‘chout_’ does not name a type
sys/charon.cpp:16:5: error: ‘chin_’ does not name a type
sys/charon.cpp:31:39: error: ‘chin_’ has not been declared
sys/charon.cpp:31:55: error: ‘engine_input’ was not declared in this scope
sys/charon.cpp:32:40: error: ‘chout_’ has not been declared
sys/charon.cpp:32:57: error: ‘engine_output’ was not declared in this scope
```

charon.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace charon_in;
using namespace charon_out;

namespace charon
{
  class charon_
  {
  private:
    chout_ engine_output;
    chin_ engine_input;
    boost::thread input_thread;
    boost::thread output_thread;
    void start_threads();
    void stop_threads();
  public:
    //Methods
};
```

chin.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <borland/conio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace charon;
using namespace charon_out;

namespace charon_in
{
  class chin_
  {
  private:
    bool pause;
    charon_* engine;
    inline iostream grab();
  public:
    //Methods
};
```

I triple checked everything. So I am pretty confident the syntax is correct, but obviously I'm missing some key concept otherwise the compiler wouldn't complain.

(I know putting classes in the cpp files isn't a standard thing to do, but I know it is possible to do it so that's why I chose to try.)

I can't see what mistakes I've made. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 25k views and 4 upvotes? What happened here?

Comment: I suspect because of the very general sounding title. I'm sure numerous things can pop out this error. Most of which would probably be common place for newbies like I was.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to include the header file that declares the namespace (or declare it again) before the `using directive`:

```
// using namespace test;  // Error test is not known to be a namespace
namespace test {}
using namespace test;     // Fine -- test is known
```

As Wayne correctly [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10112487/36565), you probably want to restructure your code differently, including header files that will contain the declarations and can be included in different translation units.

Answer (score 4):

You have the class declarations and the definitons in the .cpp files. You need to move the class declarations to a .h file and include it in the appropriate files that are using the class.

For example, move the following to chin.h and include chin.h in charon.cpp.

```
namespace charon_in 
{ 

  class chin_ 
  { 
  private: 
    bool pause; 

    iostream key_sequence; 
    deque<char> key_queue; 
    charon_* engine; 

    inline iostream grab(); 


  public: 
    chin_(const charon_& handle); 
    chin_(const chin_& orig); 
    ~chin_(); 

    void refresh(); 
    bool stop_check(); 
  }; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. I had been hoping to avoid doing that, but now it certainly makes sense why it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Be wary of cyclic dependencies for they can also cause the compiler to not find the namespace you require.

```
     //In rightWing.h
     include "leftWing.h"
     // code

       //In leftWing.h
     include "rightWing.h"
     // code
```